# Matlab Infinite Loop

Tags: matlab

I have this function

```
f(t) = −1.25 + 3.5 t exp(−2t) + 1.25 exp(−2t).
```

I want to make it symbolic /anonymous to call on it `laplace(f)` and `ilaplace(f)`.

When I am trying to set the function, (`t` being an array), the "Continue entering statement" text appears. 
What can I do?

Also, I have to find  reversed laplace for `F(s) = 10(s+1) / s(s^2+4s+5)` . What should I use?

Comment: Is this copy-and-paste from your code?  Your minus sign is UNICODE, instead of a standard ASCII hyphen.

Comment: ok that was stupid thanks :))

Comment: @Peter: This can happen when copying from a pdf. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

As explained in Matlab's manual http://nl.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/laplace.html

```
syms t
f = −1.25 + 3.5*t*exp(−2*t) + 1.25*exp(−2*t)
laplace(f, t)
```